# Read IMAP packets from a tcpdump file in JAVA

Tags: java, networking

I have to write a program in Java called ImapSniffer.java that analyzes all IMAP packets (i.e., packets with a source or destination port of 143) that are contained in a tcpdump file and that outputs all captured valid IMAP username/password pairs when it terminates. A valid username/password pair is a username and a password that has been accepted by the IMAP server.
After reading all IMAP packets from the tcpdump file the program should exit with the exit code 0 as soon as all the captured usernames and passwords have been printed to . In case of errors (e.g., wrong number of arguments, file not found, etc.) the program should exit with the exit code 1

All I found on the internet was programs that sniffed the packets from the devices attached to the systems (Listening to the live traffic from the network device) but none them had any code to sniff the data from a saved file that already has all the packets POP3 , http IMAP etc ....

All I need is a step by step tutorial that how to do it .. I am beginner to java and this is my first encounter with it.. Any help or link will do the job ...

Comment: "In case of errors (e.g., wrong number of arguments, file not found, etc.) the program should exit with the exit code 1" <-- bad. The JVM exits with 1 if `main()` throws an unhandled exception. How will you distinguish that from a user input error?

Comment: search for "java pcap offline" and you'll find enough resources